# Sort with a function or method in Go?

Tags: sorting, go

The `sort` package provides these functions for sorting the builtin slice types:

- `sort.Ints(a []int)`
- `sort.Float64s(a []float64)`
- `sort.Strings(a []string)`

It also provides these types for converting the builtin slice types to named types with `Len()`, `Less()`, `Search()`, `Sort()`, and `Swap()` methods:

- `sort.IntSlice`
- `sort.Float64Slice`
- `sort.StringSlice`

That means I can sort a slice of ints like this...

```
// Function
slice := []int{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
sort.Ints(slice) // sort in place
```

or like this...

```
// Method
slice := sort.IntSlice{5, 4, 3, 2, 1}
slice.Sort() // also sort in place
```

Is it preferable to sort with a function or a method? Are there times when one form should be preferred over the other?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition of `sort.Ints(x)` is literally `sort.Sort(sort.IntSlice(x))` so it really doesn't matter. The former is shorter, so I'd use that.